# Scheduling Azure Virtual Machine (VM) Startup with Tags

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am trying to put some auto start policy on my VM on Azure.
So, I used automation account and power shell script to do this from this link: https://adamtheautomator.com/azure-vm-schedule/

But on testing it give me error of `Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login`
Please suggest how to fix this?

```
## Get the Azure Automation Acount Information
$azConn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name 'AzureRunAsConnection'

## Add the automation account context to the session
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $azConn.TenantID -ApplicationId $azConn.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $azConn.CertificateThumbprint

## Get the Azure VMs with tags matching the value '10am'
$azVMs = Get-AzureRMVM | Where-Object {$_.Tags.StartTime -eq '10am'}

## Start VMs
$azVMS | Start-AzureRMVM
```

Regards
ESNGSRJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the Run As account isn't configured appropriately. You will need to [create one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/create-run-as-account) to provide authentication for managing resources on the Azure Resource Manager using Automation runbooks.

When you create a Run As account, it performs the following tasks:

- Creates an Azure AD application with a self-signed certificate, creates a service principal account for the application in Azure AD, and assigns the Contributor role for the account in your current subscription.
- Creates an Automation certificate asset named `AzureRunAsCertificate` in the specified Automation account.
- Creates an Automation connection asset named `AzureRunAsConnection` in the specified Automation account.

Please note the following requirements from the referenced link:

> - You must have an Azure Automation Account **with an Azure Run As account already prepared**. If you don’t have this yet, learn how to create one when you go to Create a new Automation account in the Azure portal.
> - The Azure PowerShell module must be installed. If you don’t have this yet, please go to the Install the Azure PowerShell module page for more information.

**Note:** You can configure your Runbook to use managed identities as well and it has added benefits as compared to using Run As accounts. You can get started with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity) to use managed identity.

Comment: Thanks But when i am trying to use Run as account for my automation account on azure portal it recommend to 
this by to use Managed Identities for the automation  account instead of Runas. Managed identity would be more secure.

Comment: I google and every blog i see done by Run as account only .

Comment: Sure, I suggested Run As since the link you were following needs it. You can configure your Runbook to use managed identities as well and it has added benefits as compared to using Run As accounts. You can get started with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/powershell-runbook-managed-identity) to use managed identity.

Comment: Updated my response with this detail. Please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it helpful. :)